# Build .NET DLLs from Python code?

Tags: python, dll, build, ironpython, compilation

How do I make a DLL (.NET) written in python code (IronPython)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot create a standard .NET .dll from IronPython code (.dll that can be used directly from C# or VB).

`pyc.py` produces .dll that can be used only by IronPython - check such .dll with Reflector and you will understand why.

Answer (score 1):

You can probably use ironpycompiler, using examples in http://pythonhosted.org//ironpycompiler/html-en/command-line.html. It requires installations of both IronPython and of CPython (the regular Python).

Comment: From the documentation:
IronPyCompiler is a library for compiling IronPython scripts requiring modules from the Python standard library (or third-party pure-Python modules) into a stand-alone .NET assembly (a DLL file or an executable), using pyc.py.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the script at `C:\Program Files\[IronPython Program Directory]\Tools\Scripts`.

Comment: The question is if I can compile them into portable DLLs

Comment: You mean DLLs that can be used from C#?  I don't think that's possible.  I could be wrong.

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant. but I meant it should be attached to the project, not to be called with <DllImport> or other tough way.