# How to create Revit Add-In DLL from Python

Tags: python, add-in, revit

I did a dumb thing. I got all excited about Revit 2014 allowing macros in Ruby, installed RevitRubyShell, and wrote what is going to become an add-in.

Slight problem -- there's no DLL compiler for IronRuby. D'oh!

So, I'm going to convert my code to Python (and use the excellent RevitPythonShell), which is what I was using for Revit API work before Revit 2014 Ruby came along.

My question is -- after I've converted my Ruby code to Python, (how) can I create a Revit Add-In DLL? I know that you can compile Python to a .NET DLL, but every example of Revit Add-Ins seems to be in C#. I want to stay in the interpreted environment because it's very fast to develop in Revit this way. But there's no point in doing all my dev in Python (or Ruby) if I have to convert everything to C# to make an Add-in that conforms to the IExternalApplication interface.

Has anyone done a Revit Add-In in Python?

Thanks!

Andy

Comment: what are your reasons for wanting to compile the project? Hide the source? Or easy deployment?

Comment: Easy deployment, more than anything. I'm going to open source the code. And I ended up figuring out how to install the Ruby code in a Revit macro module at startup, so I'm passing on making an add-in DLL for now.

Comment: This question (I'm the OP) has over 1000 views now, so since there's been that much attention paid to it, I'll say this, which may be of interest to future readers: I've converted all my Revit add-ins to C# and Visual Studio Express. I've found that it's just an easier environment for creating and debugging Revit add-ins.

Comment: +1, I also think C# is a great language to develop in. The RPS was born as a way to test bits and pieces of a C# Addin without restarting Revit (Version 9 at the time, I think) and also testing bits of API / exploration... Probably a mixed mode of trying stuff out quickly in RPS and then casting it into C# concrete would be what I would use for professional Addin development.

Comment: Good point! My add-ins often do things that require restarts regardless, so I wasn't giving up _that_ benefit of RPS when I switched. I just bit the bullet on losing the other benefits. :) Probably the VS debugging and the volume of C# Revit code examples on the web are why I'm happy enough just doing it all in C#. That, and I barely know Python . . .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out this blog post: [Deploying RPS scripts with DeployRpsAddin](http://darenatwork.blogspot.ch/2013/05/deploying-rps-scripts-with.html).

In that article, I describe a functionality of the [RevitPythonShell](https://code.google.com/p/revitpythonshell/), that let's you create a distributable version of your RevitPythonShell (RPS) scripts - a bunch of scripts to ship.

The main way this is done is by providing a wrapper DLL written in C# that stores your scripts and a configuration file as resources and executes them with IronPython at runtime. This still means that your python code is not "compiled" to IL, but you get to bundle it up for installation on a separate computer. Check out the [DesignPerformanceViewer](http://www.designperformance.net/?p=215) for an elaborate example of such an AddIn.

Comment: Daren, thanks -- since this wasn't strictly an RPS question, I didn't want to ask you directly, and I appreciate your usual fast response, even after my "never mind".

Answer (score 0):

Never mind. After more digging, found this stackoverflow answer that indicates IronPython DLLs are NOT portable/callable from anything but IronPython, so that leaves out Revit Add-ins.

[Build .NET DLLs from Python code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3176599/build-net-dlls-from-python-code) (the answer, per this link, is "No.")